# Visudo sanity check for the whole ecosystem of included files?

Tags: sudo

Is it possible to perform a `visudo` sanity check for a file in the context of other files included from `/etc/sudoers.d`?

**Scenario:**

I want to add a new file to `/etc/sudoers.d` the file itself is correct and it passes the `visudo -c` parser.

It does however contain a `Cmnd_Alias` line which conflicts with another file in `etc/sudoers.d`.

If moved to a `/etc/sudoers.d` it would break the `sudo` command with `Alias '<name>' already defined near line` error.

**Question:**

Is there any method which I could employ to check if the new file wouldn't break the `sudo` after placing it in `sudoers.d`?

Or is there any method to make `sudo` ignore/stop processing included files if there was any error encountered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try checking a concatenation of `/etc/sudoers` and the proposed new file:

```
sudo bash -c 'visudo -cf <(cat /etc/sudoers /path/to/to-be-added-file)'
```

Since `visudo` will parse the `#includedir` in `/etc/sudoers`, all the relevant files in `sudoers.d` would be checked as well.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/foo
Cmnd_Alias FOO = /bin/bar
$ sudo cat /tmp/bar
Cmnd_Alias FOO = /bin/foo
$ sudo bash -c 'visudo -cf <(cat /etc/sudoers /tmp/bar)'
>>> /dev/fd/63: Alias `FOO' already defined near line 31 <<<
parse error in /dev/fd/63 near line 31
```